# Cluster Openshift on AWS with IPI, installation error no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to deploy an OpenShift cluster on AWS using the IPI installation. I've used a t3.xlarge instance and followed the steps in the following guide https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-vpc.html#installation-configure-proxy_installing-aws-vpc, using my existing VPC.

After successfully completing all the steps for configuration and downloading the installation file, when I run the command ./openshift-install create cluster --dir path/todir, I encounter the errors shown below.

```
ERROR Attempted to gather debug logs after installation failure: failed to create SSH client: failed to use the provided keys for authentication: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
ERROR Attempted to gather ClusterOperator status after installation failure: listing ClusterOperator objects: Get "
https://api.openshift-cluster.dummytest.eu:6443/apis/config.openshift.io/v1/clusteroperators":
dial tcp: lookup api.openshift-cluster.dummytest.eu on 10.232.192.2:53: no such host
ERROR Bootstrap failed to complete: Get "
https://api.openshift-cluster.dummytest.eu:6443/version":
dial tcp: lookup api.openshift-cluster.dummytest.eu on 10.232.192.2:53: no such host
ERROR Failed waiting for Kubernetes API. This error usually happens when there is a problem on the bootstrap host that prevents creating a temporary control plane.
```

I'd like to add that I've generated the SSH key, created a hosted zone on Route 53, and checked the internet permissions. I didn't specify the subnets in the install-config.yml, but only indicated a single availability zone and default IP addresses for machine CIDR and cluster CIDR. However, I'm unable to proceed further.

This is my install-config.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: dummytest.eu
credentialsMode: Manual
controlPlane:   
  hyperthreading: Enabled 
  name: master
  platform:
    aws:
      iamRole: openshift-ec2-role
      zones:
      - eu-south-1a
      rootVolume:
        iops: 4000
        size: 500
        type: io1 
      metadataService:
        authentication: Optional 
      type: t3.xlarge
  replicas: 1
compute: 
- hyperthreading: Enabled 
  name: worker
  platform:
    aws:
      rootVolume:
        iops: 2000
        size: 500
        type: io1 
      metadataService:
        authentication: Optional 
      type: c5.4xlarge
      zones:
      - eu-south-1a
  replicas: 0
metadata:
  name: openshift-cluster 
networking:
  clusterNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.128.0.0/14
    hostPrefix: 23
  machineNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.0.0.0/16
  networkType: OVNKubernetes 
  serviceNetwork:
  - 172.30.0.0/16
platform:
  aws:
    region: eu-south-1 
    propagateUserTags: true 
    userTags:
      adminContact: jdoe
      costCenter: 7536
    subnets: 
    amiID: ami-01317af8d99bf5105  
fips: false 
pullSecret: ''
```

While searching online, some sources suggested that the problem might lie in the failure to create the Route 53 hosted zone. However, as mentioned, the hosted zone is public and was created earlier. Also, seems that openshift have created other resources like (EIP, NAT gateway and a private hosted zone managed with terraform, roles for bootstrap,worker and master nodes) but don't complete the installation
Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for the help